# CSS- How to create child menu towards leftern side

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

Hi all my goal is to get the child menu expanded towards the left hand side instead of the right hand side.
The CSS is as follows,

```
    /*<![CDATA[*/

/* page styling, unimportant for the menu. only makes the page looks nicer */

/* - - - ADxMenu: BASIC styles - - - */

/* remove all list stylings */
.menu, .menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
}

/* move all list items into one row, by floating them */
.menu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: block;
    float: left;                /* modified by poornima. (default float :right ) */
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}

/* define new starting point for the nested UL, thus making positioning it a piece of cake */
.menu li:hover {
    position: relative;
}

/* align the submenus with the right edge */
.menu li ul {
    right: 0;
    margin-left:-385px;       /* already setted value: -363px;*/    /* IE 7 & 8 Problem to bring the submenu for left side */
}

/* force the submenu items into separate rows, while still keeping float:left (which resolves IE6 white-gap problem) */
.menu li li {
    width: 100%;
}

/* fix the position for 2nd level submenus.
    first make sure no horizontal scrollbars are visible on initial page load by sliding them all into top-left corner  */
.menu li li ul {
    top: 0;
}

/* ...and then place the submenu where it should be when shown */
.menu li li:hover ul {
    right: 100%;
    padding-right:52px; /*Newly added property for submenu hover properly*/
}

/* initialy hide all sub menus */
.menu ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

/* display them on hover */
.menu li:hover>ul {
    visibility: visible;
}

/* -- float.clear -- force containment of floated LIs inside of UL */
.menu:after, .menu ul:after {
    content: ".";
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
/* IE7 float clear: */
.menu, .menu ul {
    min-height: 0;
}
/* -- float.clear.END --  */

/* sticky submenu: it should not disappear when your mouse moves a bit outside the submenu
    YOU SHOULD NOT STYLE the background of the ".menu UL" or this feature may not work properly!
    if you do it, make sure you 110% know what you do */
.menu ul {
    background-image: url(empty.gif);/* required for sticky to work in IE6 and IE7 - due to their (different) hover bugs */
    padding: 10px 30px 30px 30px;
    margin: -10px -30px 0 0;
    /*background: #f00;*/       /* uncomment this if you want to see the "safe" area. you can also use to adjust the safe area to your requirement */
}


/* - - - ADxMenu: DESIGN styles - - - */

.menu, .menu ul li {
    color: #fff;

    background:transparent url(../../Images/Modern/bgnd_sel_2.jpg) repeat scroll 0 0;}

.menu li li {
    text-align: right;
}

.menu ul {
    width: 15em;
}

.menu li:hover>a {
    color: #000;
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: .2em .3em;/*padding: .2em .4em;*/
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}

li.inactive {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: .3em 1em;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000000;
}

li.inactive {color:#cccccc;}

.menu a:hover, .menu li:hover>a {
    color: #000;
    background:transparent url(../../Images/Modern/bgnd_sel_4.png) repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.menu li li {   /* create borders around each item */
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB !Important;
    margin-left:22px;      /*Move menu to right side*/
    text-align:right;      /*Move menu to right side and the text align right*/
}

.menu ul>li + li {  /* and remove the top border on all but first item in the list */
    border-top: 0;
}

.menu li li:hover>ul {  /* inset 2nd+ submenus, to show off overlapping */
    top: 5px;
    right: 100%;
    visibility:visible; /* IE 7 & 8 Problem add visibility for 2nd+ submenus */
}

/* Fix for IE5/Mac \*//*/
.menu a {
    float: left;
}
.menu {
    display: inline-block;
}
/* End Fix */

/*]]>*/
</style>

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen, tv, projection">
/*<![CDATA[*/

/* - - - ADxMenu: BASIC styles - - - */
.menu, .menu ul {
    height: 1%;
}

/* this style must be exact copy of: ".menu li li:hover ul" style above  */
.menu li li.adxmhover ul {
    right: 100%;
}

/* the following two rules simulate li:hover>ul selector
    repeat enough times to cover all nested levels
    look at www.aplus.co.yu/adxmenu/trouble/ if some of your submenus do now show up */
.adxmhover ul,
.adxmhover .adxmhover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
.adxmhover li ul, 
.adxmhover .adxmhover li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* - - - ADxMenu: DESIGN styles - - - */
.menu ul a {    /* fix clickability-area problem */
    zoom: 1;
}

.menu li li {   /* fix white gap problem */
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu li li {   /* prevent double-line between items */
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.menu a:hover, .menu .adxmhoverA {      /* li:hover>a selector */
    color: #000;
    background:transparent url(../../Images/Modern/bgnd_sel_4.png) repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.adxmhover a, .adxmhover .adxmhover a {
    color: #000;
}
.adxmhover li a, .adxmhover .adxmhover li a {
    color: #000;
}

.menu .adxmhoverUL .adxmhoverUL {   /* inset 2nd+ submenus, to show off overlapping */
    top: 5px;
    left: 100%;
}

/*]]>*/
/*</style>*/

<script type="text/javascript" src="../code/ADxMenu.v4.02.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The page's screen shot is follows
[image]

When i mouse hover  "user management" menu, the "create user" must get expanded onto the left hand side. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you paste your CSS we might be able to help you.

Comment: Some question formatting would help too..

Comment: Leftern? Is that something like western?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a comment on your code, it says

> /* ...and then place the submenu where it should be when shown */

after this you have the following

```
.menu li li:hover ul {
    right: 100%;
    padding-right:52px;
}
```

so I suppose if you change the `padding-right` to `padding-left` and `right:100%` to `left:100%` *maybe* you can change the menu.

The best way to help you, is to give us a live example on [jsbin.com](http://www.jsbin.com)